# How to uncheck selected checkboxes when condition meets in checkboxlist?

Tags: asp.net

I want to uncheck selected checkboxes when condition meets.I can able to uncheck all of them using Checkboxlist1.ClearSelection(); method.But requirement is uncheck the checkboxes which are selected when condition satisfies.Any help is appreciated.

```
public int count;
public static int i =0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 

}
protected void chkboxlist1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int conver = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ddlseats"].ToString());
        if (i >= conver)
        {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "alert('Not More than'" + Session["ddlseats"] + "' seat(s) can be selected');", true);
                chkboxlist1.ClearSelection(chkboxlist1.Items[i].Selected);//error
        }
        else
        {
            if (chkboxlist1.SelectedItem.Selected == true && chkboxlist1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearselection does not take in any input parameter. You can directly invoke that.
Like this `chkboxlist1.ClearSelection();` .

To just uncheck , single one ( iterating in loop), use following.
`chkboxlist1.Items[i].Selected = false;`

Comment: Hi Arindam, if I invoke ClearSelection() method, all the checked boxes which are required are getting unchecked.

Comment: Do you want , specific checkbox that are selected need to be unchecked?

Comment: Yes Arindam, when user selects 2 seats from dropdownlist in previous page, here in this seat selection page he has to select only 2 seats.So, when he selected another extra seat from checkboxlist, the 3rd selected seat i.e.,checkbox, has to be unchecked shown with an alert.

Comment: @Swamy , i have updated my code, check if that helps!

Comment: Thanks Arindam, will get back to you.Thanks for your prompt reply. :)

Comment: @Swamy, does this help? or still having issue?

Comment: @Swamy - Did you update the question, it is missing `for` loop, can you updated that in code, in case if that is missed!

Comment: Actually Arindam, I have taken 'static int i=0'.So, I dont think for loop is required. As you suggested, I was trying to do so. But can we solve according to above code irrespective of using for loop.

Comment: If you are not using `for` [since you said `I am failing at for loop`], then it will always reset 1st checkbox list item, if you do `chkboxlist1.ClearSelection();` it will reset all checkbox selection, and other is explained above or just go through my answer once again!